# Is it a good idea to memoize all of my react components?

Tags: reactjs

I've recently decided to refresh on react's documentation and came across https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo (React.memo).

At first glance it looked like a good candidate for pretty much all of my function components. So I did just that and applied `memo` on all of them.

I'm not sure if I am able to notice dramatic performance boost, but it for sure didn't make anything slower.

Hence the question: should I apply memo to all my fucntion components by default, just in case so I can catch edge cases of re-rendering a lot of elements? Are there any drawbacks to this / something else i need to be aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you shouldn't memoize all your function components by default. You should decide when to do this on a case-by-case basis.

### 1. It's only for "pure" function components (as in, without side effects)

From the documentation:

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result.

Imagine that you add some side effect to your function component, for example, reading the current time from `Date.now()`. The component will work as expected the first time it's called with certain props, but the next time it's called with those same props, the old time will be used. This can lead to confusing bugs.

### 2. Not all pure function components will benefit from memoization

For example, if it's unlikely a component will ever be called with the same props, then memoizing the result will likely lead to *worse* performance. After all, memoization is just storing the result of a function call to an object, where the key is derived from the input to the function and the value is the result of the function call. Why store this if you'll never use it?

### 3. Memoization is more useful for functions that are computation intensive

If your function component doesn't take many CPU cycles to render, then any performance optimization is likely going to be negligible. But it's now possible to later add side effects to that component, forget that it's being memoized, and waste time fixing the resulting bugs.

Again, from the docs:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

For shorter explanation:

If `React.memo()` everything makes React more efficient and optimized, it should be considered as a default behavior, not only an option (like pure function).

Basically, `React.memo()` prevents redundant rerenders by **comparing** the component's previous and current props.

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

Normally, when the `Parent` rerenders, the `Child` rerender as well by default.

With `React.memo()`, if the props passed into `Child` are not changed when `Parent` rerender, `Child` does not rerender.

**The question here is**: why does React know props passed to `Child` was not changed in the current rerender?

**The answer is**: React itself has to do a comparison, and it is the cost of `React.memo()`

If the time to comparison > the time to just rerender the whole `Child` component, it even slows down your app.