# Is it a bad practice to memoize everything in React?

Tags: reactjs

I know that using `React.memo()` to memoize components / parts of components is generally a good practice, but I find myself memoizing every single field on forms implemented using React Hook Form. Since RHF uses uncontrolled components, it does not seem to be a problem: the components seem to update just fine, and I do see a performance improvement.

Still, my instinct tells me that memoizing almost *everything* is a bad practice. Is it a bad practice? Is there some other way that I should economize on renders?

Answer (score 7):

Your instinct is correct. If `React.memo()` everything makes React more efficient, it should be a default behavior, not only an optional (like pure function).

For shorter explanation:

`React.memo()` prevents some redundant rerender by **comparing** the component's previous and current props.

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

Normally, when the parent rerenders, the child rerenders as well by default.

If the props passed into `Child` are not changed when `Parent` rerender, `Child` does not rerender if you use `React.memo()` on `Child`

**The question here is**: why React knows props on `Child` was not changed in the current rendering phase?

The answer is: React itself has to do a comparison, and it is the cost of `React.memo()`

If the time to comparison > the time to just rerender the whole `Child` component, it even slows down your rerendering time.

You only need to use `React.memo()` for some huge things (Table with a lot of rows and for some reasons it does not have pagination).

Answer (score 0):

I would say YES it is pretty redundant to memoize everything. I would recommend using [react profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html), to know which components need memoization.

I would refer to this answer as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024157/7174241